# How to Click "Accept Cookies" on a page without an ID or Name with Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

i am trying to figure out how to click a button called "Alles akzeptieren" to accept the cookies of the website. On other websites I used an ID or a name where it worked. But on this website I can't get access to the button and click it. The HTML looks like this:

```
<button tabindex="0" title="Alle akzeptieren" aria-label="Alle akzeptieren" class="message-component message-button no-children button-responsive-primary" path="[0,1,1,0]" style="padding: 5px 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(50, 100, 255); border-radius: 4px; border-style: solid; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; width: calc(100% - 0px); background: rgb(50, 100, 255);">Alle akzeptieren</button>
```

The Xpath is:
/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button

I tried the following code:

```
#accept cookies
time.sleep(5)
AcceptCookies = driver.find_element_by_link_text_name("Alles Akzeptieren")
AcceptCookies.click
```

Or

```
#accept cookies
time.sleep(5)
AcceptCookies = driver.find_element_by_class_name("message-component message-button no-children button-responsive-primary")
AcceptCookies.click
```

Does somebody know what the problem is?
When I use this code I get the Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".message-component message-button no-children button-responsive-primary"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
```

Or

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_link_text_name'
```

Comment: Dont answer as part of question. Edit your question and put additional code there.

Comment: The `Accept Cookies` button is inside an `iframe`. Need to swith the iframe first and then interact with button element.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no href attribute in your button so find_element_by_link_text will not work you can use xpath

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.

I still get the ERROR:
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Alles Akzeptieren"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)

Comment: sorry you had not submitted proper information before.. now you please inspect this element in your driver and copy full xpath and  use find_element_by_xpath("paste your full path here")

Comment: Hello,

I tried it your way: the full xpath is: /html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button

so i used this code:

AcceptCookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button")

But i still get the same error, that it is unable to locate the element

Comment: how many tabs you have on the driver while clicking on the button??

Answer (score 0):

Try with this css locator:

```
AcceptCookies = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[title='Alle akzeptieren']")
```

Comment: Hello,

I tried your code but I still have the same outcome:

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[title='Alle akzeptieren']"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)

Comment: Hm, thy this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(., 'Alle akzeptieren')]")`

Comment: I appreciate your help

But I still am unable to find the element.
The full xpath is : /html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/button

So i tried this xpath to by copy and paste and still am unable to click it

Comment: Are you sure the button is not inside of an iframe or a pop up message? Can you share more of the HTML?